# How to refrain from storing credentials in the code in C# ASP.NET core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I have to ensure that authentication has been set up to restrict access to the API.
And to do that I believe I have to add security or authentication to a web app under the appsettings.json by making appsettings with password not visible.

I have tried removing credentials the password on the link under the appsettings file. So I am not really sure as to whether this is the problem or not. But after I left them visible. The API is published to the service hosted on Azure for it to be secure and accessible.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73590371/281278) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing secrets in AppSettings.json, you should use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview).

Comment: Alright thank you, will do.